# Validating URL from drag and drop in a sandbox

Tags: macos, swift3, drag-and-drop, appstore-sandbox, nspasteboard

With [file access in a sandboxed osx app with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278869/file-access-in-a-sandboxed-osx-app-with-swift) in mind, does it work the same with URLs provided via Finder or other apps drops?

As there's no NSOpenPanel call to afford folder access as in this example, just urls - I think the folder access is implicit since the user dragged the file from the source / desktop "folder" much the same as implicit selection via the open dialog.

I have not begun the sandbox migration yet but wanted to verify my thinking was accurate, but here's a candidate routine that does **not** work in sandbox mode:

```
func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> Bool {
    let pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
    let items = pboard.pasteboardItems

    if (pboard.types?.contains(NSURLPboardType))! {
        for item in items! {
            if let urlString = item.string(forType: kUTTypeURL as String) {
                self.webViewController.loadURL(text: urlString)
            }
            else
            if let urlString = item.string(forType: kUTTypeFileURL as String/*"public.file-url"*/) {
                let fileURL = NSURL.init(string: urlString)?.filePathURL
                self.webViewController.loadURL(url: fileURL!)
            }
            else
            {
                Swift.print("items has \(item.types)")
            }
        }
    }
    else
    if (pboard.types?.contains(NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey))! {
        Swift.print("we have NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey")
    }
    return true
}
```

as no URL is acted upon or error thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the file access is implicit. As the sandbox implementation is poorly documented and had/has many bugs, you want to work around URL and Filenames. The view should register itself for both types at initialisation. Code is in Objective-C, but API should be the same.

```
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, nil]];
```

Then on performDragOperation:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    BOOL dragPerformed = NO;
    NSPasteboard *paste = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSArray *typesWeRead = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, nil];
    //a list of types that we can accept
    NSString *typeInPasteboard = [paste availableTypeFromArray:typesWeRead];

    if ([typeInPasteboard isEqualToString:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {
        NSArray *fileArray = [paste propertyListForType:@"NSFilenamesPboardType"];
        //be careful since this method returns id.  
        //We just happen to know that it will be an array. and it contains strings.
        NSMutableArray *urlArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[fileArray count]];
        for (NSString *path in fileArray) {
            [urlArray addObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
        }
        dragPerformed = //.... do your stuff with the files;
    } else if ([typeInPasteboard isEqualToString:NSURLPboardType]) {
        NSURL *droppedURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:paste];
        if ([droppedURL isFileURL]) {
            dragPerformed = //.... do your stuff with the files;
        }
    }
    return dragPerformed;
}
```